# AEM Custom error logs not reflecting under log support

Tags: logging, aem-6

I have created custom log file ilunder config folder in crxde , but I couldn't view that under Log support in Felix console. Below is the link that I have referred, any help is appreciated.

I can't create a new file under log support in Felix console, as I don't have permissions in my prod server.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/custom_log_file.html

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a simple Sling OSGi config for LogManager API in CRX/DE and it is working for me. Make sure you do not have any typo in any of the properties or node names.
Below is what I have created -

[image]

And in the ***./system/console/slinglog (Log Support)*** console, I have automatically created on refreshing the page is below -

[image]

The only reason I can think that you are not able to create the config in Felix Console is some sort of typo error while defining property names/values or node names.

Remember that since Log Manager is a factory config, you need to give some custom suffix at the end of the name. For e.g., in ***org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-logsample-model*** - the custom suffix is - ***logsample-model***

I hope this helps.